# How to do a Count(*) in Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to mimic SQL code converting to Python. The SQL is something like this -

```
SELECT Category, Type, Code, Description, count(*), avg(Days) 
FROM File 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

I got everything else in Python, but not sure how I can do the count(*)?

My python code is

```
df2 = df1 (['Category','Type','Code','Description'])['Days'].mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GroupBy.Aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) to pass a list of aggregate functions.

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Category','Type','Code','Description'])\
   ['Days'].agg(['size','mean']).reset_index()
```

Comment: wouldn't this just be taking the count from 'Days'?

Comment: right. count of days should be the same as count of all records, unless you have NaNs in which case the mean aggregate would error out